# VueJS can't update component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have this `Vue 1` component that gets an object as a prop that has to be filled by the user.

This object has this structure:

```
{
    property1: ...,
    property2: ...,
    inputs: {
        2130: { value: ..., comment: ... },
        2131: { ... },
        ...,
    }

}
```

This component is a simple modal with a table containing all necessary inputs. I'd like to check some stuff, make calculations and change styles of cells depending on user input.

When the modal loads I build the page, setting the models of those inputs with their id:

`v-model="object.inputs[subgroup[1].dx.mob.id].comment"`

(Note: `subgroup[1]` is part of another object that contains the "definition" of the table structure, by doing `inputs[subgroup[1].dx.mob.id]` I'm expecting to link the table field to the corresponding input of the object)

The problem is that, whatever I try, the page does not re-render. The `<input>` fields don't even hold the value, as soon as I click away the it disappears.

More strangely, the values are actually set, but the only way to make this component re-render and do all the nice checks and styling I need him to, is to completely recreate the component through closing and reopening the modal or by setting a `v-if` on a parent of the table.

These are obviously both non viable options as

- I need the page to be reactive
- Recreating the component (at each input change) takes too much time

This are the things I tried:

- Dynamically build a watcher per input

  - but `vm.$watch` can't find object for some reason.

```
...forEach((input, index)=>{
    vm.$watch(`object.inputs[${index}].comment`, function(){
            this.$forceUpdate();
        })
}
```

- Return inputs in a computed property and watch that

  - but the page can't detect the changes
- Manually launch `this.$forceUpdate()` on @change and @input events

  - but `$forceUpdate` is not a function
- Declare a counter in data and increment it on @change and @input events.

  - but the page still does not update.
- putting a `v-if` on an invisible object

  - but only said object gets re-rendered
- changing the :key prop of my component with a data property

  - but nothing happens

The only way I could do this, as anticipated, is by destroying and recreating the component.

Anyone has any solution?

> **Ugly Solution:** After a couple more failed attempts I found something that fixes the problem even if in an improper way. Any real
> answer is still more than welcome.
>
> Essentially I managed to force the component to re-render by:
>
> - Declaring a new variable in data, I named it `key` (in my case it was numeric, but any will do)
> - Creating an `update` function that switches `key` from 1 to 0 and vice versa.
> - Binding that function to the `@blur` event of every input or select
> - Since my whole modal is rendered depending on a computed property, I executed a couple reading operations on `key` inside this function (In
>   my case I assigned its value to a new variable and then logged it (not
>   sure which of the two triggers the render, but I'd guess the first is
>   enough))
>
> ```
> ... 
> data: function() {
>       return {
>         ... ,
>         key: 0
>       };   
> },
>
> ...
>
> methods: {
>     ... ,
>     update: function(){
>         this.key = this.key == 0 ? 1 : 0
>     }
> },
> computed: {
>     ... ,
>     testData: function () { //this functions builds an object that is used to render the page  
>         var data = []
>         var __self = this
>         var blu = this.key // This is the line where i read key
>         console.log(blu)
>         this.test.inputs.forEach(function(input){
>
>             var slug = input.slug.replaceAll('#', '').split('-')
>         
>             __self.setItem(data, slug, input)
>
>         })
>      
>         console.log('data', data)
>         return data // this value gets then passed to Object.entries() to get an iterable object I build the page with
>     } 
> }
> ```

Comment: `inputs: [ 2130: { value: ..., comment: ... }, 2131: { ... }, ..., ]` is not a valid syntax, it should be `inputs: { 2130: { value: ..., comment: ... }, 2131: { ... }, ..., }`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Are you sure? From what I have seen, numeric indexed objects in js are usually represented as arrays

Comment: where have you seen that?

Comment: @FabioR. Previous comment is correct. An array shouldn't have a keyed index. The structure is [ a, b, c ] - where the INDEX (not key) will change depending on whether elements are pushed/pulled in front of the member under consideration. Objects are keyed though - key doesn't change regardless of what happens to other keys. AND - important - IF your Array is actually an object with keyed members, keys shouldn't be integer values. Objects require strings as keys, numbers aren't valid. https://www.becomebetterprogrammer.com/can-javasscript-object-keys-be-numbers-or-non-string-values/

Comment: @TremendusApps thanks for the explanation. Might this really be the problem? That object obviously comes from an api, I didn't define it manually, so the "template" I posted is just my interpretation based on how the object is structured

Comment: In your post above, your `index` key is on the api's response object is syntactically invalid. You can't have an array with a key like this: [ 2130: <something> ]. This is object notation and would be { 2130: <something> } (not curly braces not square brackets). It's either an array in which case you probably mean inputs[2130] = <something> or its an object in which case, change your brackets to braces. So right now, I guess no-one can help cause they don't understand the problem because of this.

Comment: PS - there are other issues here too. For example, you shouldn't `$forceUpdate()` anything ... ever. Everytime I see this, its because of a misunderstanding of Vue's reactivity.  If you feel you need to do this, you've probably missed something. Vue's reactivity is very smart ... when used right - you won't need to update anything by `$watching` and `$forceUpdate`ing. But I think you need to undestand your object better, see above. Additionally - you say that Vue can't update nested properties. This is also not correct, btw. https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html

Comment: @FabioR. Basically you need to post a complete example showing: how the data is mounted on the Vue instance, how the data is changed, and what your template looks like. But first you need to accurately describe the structure of that data coming from the API.

Comment: @TremendusApps I know about the $forceUpdate, in fact I never had any problem with reactivity in depth, I have actually managed to do something similar in a different part of the application without problem and with much surprise (I was very afraid). I should have also probably mentioned that I'm stuck on Vue 1 because of customer's requirements, so things might have changed a bit. I'll try to collect more information to put in an edit.

Comment: Try, whenever something is changed within the `inputs` object, to do a reassignment like `this.inputs = { ...this.inputs }`

Answer (score 0):

## Better Answer

After an euphemistic bit of debugging I managed to solve this problem.

Essentially the component I described in the question is used in two different pages: a "creation" one and an "editing" one. My mind clicked when I saw that in the editing page everything was working as expected.

#### What was happening:

The only difference between how the component is used in the two pages is the data that is passed to it. The "editing" page has each object already filled as data already exist, while in the "creation" page each object was obviously blank.

As I needed a usable object I had to fill it with empty inputs so that I could access them later.

I stupidly tried to set the property manually like so:

```
objects[index].inputs = {}
```

Expecting that assigning a property to a reactive object would automatically make that property reactive too. Boy was I wrong.

#### Vue reactive getters and setters:

To make things reactive vue overrides the default Object class getters and setters. But this only happens with specific conditions:

- The property must be added through `Vue.set()` or `this.$set()`
- All of the parent properties must be reactive as well

For example, after a couple attempts I tried, after setting `objects[index].inputs = {}`, to use `this.$set()` to populate my inputs.

This could not work as I didn't make `.inputs` reactive as well.

So I had to

```
this.$set('objects[${index}].inputs', {})
```

before

```
this.$set(`objects[${index}].inputs[${input.id}].value`, null)
this.$set(`objects[${index}].inputs[${input.id}].comment`, null)
```

#### In Conclusion:

If you have reactivity problems my suggestion is to log said object and check if it and its parents have the right getters and setters.

And remember that if you want to add new properties to a reactive object you must `$set()` it.

###### Reactive Object:

[image: Reactive Object]

###### Non Reactive Object:

[image: Non Reactive Object]